# Obtener arreglo de diferentes tamaños

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente json:

```
[
{
 "cliente": "Milagros",
 "descripcion": "Sin ensalada",
 "detalleventa": [
   {"cantidad": 2, "producto": "Super D'Nicos"}, 
   {"cantidad": 1, "producto": "Cl\u00e1sica"},
   {"cantidad": 1, "producto": "Chicha morada"}
  ],
 "atendido": false
 },
 {
 "cliente": "Nicolas",
 "descripcion": "Todas las cremas",
 "detalleventa": [
   {"cantidad": 2, "producto": "Agregado Pollo"}, 
   {"cantidad": 1, "producto": "Hot dog frankfurt simple"}
 ],
 "atendido": false
 },
 {
  "cliente": "Hamilton",
  "descripcion": "Todas las cremas",
  "detalleventa": [
    {"cantidad": 2, "producto": "Super D'Nicos"},
    {"cantidad": 1, "producto": "Chicha morada"}
  ],
  "atendido": false
  }
]
```

En cual a través de ajax estoy obteniéndolo:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
                    url:  "{%  url 'api-pedido' %}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                }).responseText);
```

Entonces lo que quiero lograr es que apartir de esa data poder pintar unos cards de bootsrap en mi html.
Hasta el momento ya obtengo los numero de cards dependiendo el tamaño del arreglo, el nombre del **cliente** y la **descripción** pero tengo problemas con el detalleventa ya que es un array y en cada detalleventa su tamaño es distinto y no se como recuperar y ponerlos en sus respectivos li, hasta el momento logre hacer esto:

```
for (let pedidos of json) {
                for(let detalle of pedidos.detalleventa){
                $('.container').append("<div class='col-xs-auto spaceCard'><div class='card'><h5 class='card-header'>" + pedidos.cliente +"</h5><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'><span class='colorDnicos'>Descripción: </span>" + pedidos.descripcion + "</h5><div class='card-text'><ul><li>"+detalle.cantidad+ " " + detalle.producto +"</li></ul></div><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'><span class='fa fa-check'></span>Atendido</a></div</div></div>");
                }
            }
```

Pero en lugar de poner el array de detalleventa en cada card, esta creando 1 card por cada detalle:

[image: Milagros tiene 3 productos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las iteraciones que estas haciendo son correctas, pero el problema es como armas el string que luego agregas en tu `container`.

Por un lado agregas el titulo y la descripción. Luego en el otro `for` agregas cada elemento de la lista.

Deberías separarlo de la siguiente manera el contenido

```
for (let pedidos of json) {
  let content = "<div class='col-xs-auto spaceCard'><div class='card'><h5 class='card-header'>" + pedidos.cliente +"</h5><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'><span class='colorDnicos'>Descripción: </span>" + pedidos.descripcion + "</h5><div class='card-text'><ul>"

  for(let detalle of pedidos.detalleventa){
    content += "<li>"+detalle.cantidad+ " " + detalle.producto +"</li>";
  }

  content += "</ul></div><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'><span class='fa fa-check'></span>Atendido</a></div</div></div>";

  $('.container').append(content);
}
```

puedes ver tu ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/19436/)

saludos

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias. No sabia como separarlo pero ya con este ejemplo es más que suficiente. Un abrazo!